# Realtime Updates with Cloud Firestore and local changes

Tags: android, listener, google-cloud-firestore

In what case will not the local change fire here. Reading the [firestore query-data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen). The `SnapshotListener` should fire twice on the device that both write and listen to the same `collection` or `document`.

Writing to a Cloud Firestore collection adding a chat message and listening (from same device)should make the `SnapshotListener` `Eventlistener` fire first for the local cache  and then when the data is written to server. I dont see this hppening only the server trigger like "Server":

```
String source = snapshot != null && snapshot.getMetadata().hasPendingWrites()
                ? "Local" : "Server";
```

Any ide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this was that I used a Transaction when writing to Cloud Firestore databasw. Transactions don't write to cache.

Comment: What did you use as alternative to transaction?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know when your write has completed, you can listen to the completion callback rather than using hasPendingWrites. But remember, completion callback only fires once the server acknowledges the request. This interface is used as a method of being notified when an operation has been acknowledged by the Database servers and can be considered complete. In case you are offline, completion callback does not fire at all.